# Javascript: Code does not work but has no error on it

Tags: javascript

So I wanted to be able to enter any value in object and destination text bar to displayed the result. However, my reset button worked, but the Process button does not work. Apparently the function is not being called, but I don't know why the function is not being called.

```
<html>


<head>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!-- hide script from uneducated browsers
      function newVerse(form)
      {
            obect = form.object.value
            destination = form.destination.value
            var result
            result = "Where have all the " + object + " gone?<br />"+ "Long time passing.<br />"+ "Where have all the " + object + " gone? <br />"+ "Long time ago.<br />"+ "Where have all the " + object + " gone?.<br />" + "Gone to " + destination + " everyone.<br />"+
           "When will they ever learn?<br />"+ "When will they ever learn?<br />"
            return result
      }
      // end script hiding from uneducated browsers -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
   <b>Object</b>: <input TYPE="text" NAME="object" ID="objectID" />
   <p>
   <b>Destination</b>: <input Type="text" Name="destination" ID="destinationID" />
   </p><p>
   <textarea TYPE="textarea" NAME="text" ID="textID" rows="1" cols="50" /> </textarea>
   <p>
   <input TYPE="Reset"/>
   <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Process" onClick="newVerse(this.form)"

   </p><p>
</form>


<i>(lyrics by Pete Seeger)</i>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had problem adding code block, this is my first time using this website. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No error? It throws "ReferenceError: object is not defined". (Open the console tab to see error messages.)

Comment: Check your console log—it is throwing errors, and you should be reading them to help you with troubleshooting.

Comment: Insert code. Selector code. Click `{}` button. Done.

Comment: Start by looking for typos and misspelled variable names.

Comment: FWIW, the function is called but you are not doing anything with the return value. Since you didn't describe the expected outcome we can't really help you in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on `object` as you assigned a var to `obect`. You are also missing some `var`s (and making your variables global which is a bad practice).

I suggest the following:

```
function newVerse(form)
  {
        var object = form.object.value
        var destination = form.destination.value
        var result = "Where have all the " + object + " gone?<br />"+ "Long time passing.<br />"+ "Where have all the " + object + " gone? <br />"+ "Long time ago.<br />"+ "Where have all the " + object + " gone?.<br />" + "Gone to " + destination + " everyone.<br />"+
       "When will they ever learn?<br />"+ "When will they ever learn?<br />"
        return result
  }
```